# How to show that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}g(\bar{X})=g(u)$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let ${X_n, n\geq 1}$ be a sequence of i.i.d random variables, and g a bounded continuous function. Write $u=E(X_1)$ and $\bar{X}=n^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$

How to show that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}g(\bar{X})=g(u)$

It seems that WLLN should be applied.

Can anyone give some suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking for almost sure convergence of $g(\overline {X}) $ then WLLN's is not enough. You need SLLN.

By SLLN's $\overline {X} \to u$ almost surely so continuity of $g$ yields the result.